# css help: only webkit rendering li bullets, which should be hidden

Tags: css

http://horizon.hoffmangraphics.com/products/international-products/

in chrome/safari, square bullets are visible next to product titles, and the alignment is incorrect.

Firefox & EVEN IE, the layout looks correct. Adding padding to h5 can fix alignment of product image and title, but breaks layout in working browsers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#page-content ul li {
     list-style-type: none;
 }
```

I entered this in chrome's web inspector and worked!

But it broke the layout in all browsers. Adding `padding-top: 24px;` to `h5` seemed to cure the problem.